# Make equivalent pandas dataframe for sql query containing: join table on itself with selecting all column of 1st table and some column of right table

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on python pandas.
I have one table `table_one` which has columns `name,address,one,two,phone`.
Now `one` is foreign_key on `two`

Now i want pandas to do the join on this foreign key and resulted data freame should give result like below:

Input dta frame

```
Id name Address one two nuber
1 test | addrs | 1 | 2 | number
2 fert | addrs | 2 | 1 | testnumber
3 dumy | addrs | 3 | 9 | testnumber
```

Ouptput should be:

join this `df`(data frame) to itself and get name for its foreign key which is two
o/p:
Get all column of left table and only name from right table in pandas
Means ext row 1: `one` is foreign key on `two` so resulted op will be

```
1 test addrs 1 2 number fert
```

same for all means for row 1 `one` value 1 is mapped to column `two` which is row 2 having value 1 for column `two' so take name`fert` in resulted new column.

I tried below

```
pd.merge(df, df, left_on=['one'], right_on=['two'])
```

but not getting required result it is giving all column for right table also but i want only `name` value with all coulmn of left table..

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select required columns before merge (rename it to avoid conflict)

```
pd.merge(df, df[['two', 'name']].rename(columns={'name', 'for_name'}), left_on=['one'], right_on=['two'])
```

Comment: Actually this one is right one but i did this by research before you post answer.By the way thanks a lot for your help.